# SVR is ignoring 'outliers' in my data set, and not capturing the more 'extreme' values

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm using Scikit-learn's SVR to model the income of professors based on a few parameters. My scatter plot for income and ONE of the parameters looks like this:

[image]

I'm only showing one of the parameters, since I don't know how to plot multi-dimensional plots, but that explains the chaotic plot of the model result.

Essentially what you see is the SVR output only covering the midrange to low range salaries. This is true for essentially all of my combinations of the grid-search I'm using to calibrate the SVR. Specifically, my grid parameters are:

```
epsilon_svr = [0.01, 0.1, 0.5, 1]
C_svr = [1,3,5]
```

My question is how can I capture that upper end, and dramatically improve my model, especially that R^2. I know SVR tends to be used for outlier detection, and it's possible it's selecting those points up there as outliers, but how do I improve the model fit. It seems like the exhaustive grid search for my measly 7 parameters may not be enough to fully capture my model?

Comment: What kernel are you using ? Have you tried others ?

Comment: @TheWalkingCube I have a grid-search for rbf and linear. It keeps selecting linear as the best fit, so I removed poly. 

I should force it to choose poly, but the calculation drains up so much time.

Comment: Have you scaled your data and grid-searched gamma for the rbf kernel?

Comment: @AndreasMueller Hmm.. I've only grid-searched epsilon and C. I want to keep C low. My grid search keeps selecting a high C if I allow it to select the very low epsilon. But then I don't want it to be so general that R^2 goes down as well. I'll try rbf. Parameter adjusting SVR is tough.

Comment: What do you mean by "you want to keep C low"? I don't understand you comment about R^2 going down. Don't you grid-search against R^2 (the default). Just ``logs = np.logspace(-3, 0, 4); GridSearchCV(SVR(), param_grid={'epsilon': logs, 'C': logs, 'gamma': logs})`` should be a good start, I think.

Comment: The parameter C represents the complexity, doesn't it? Having a high C I could imagine it overfitting. But thanks! I'll try the grid search component. I'm starting to think, it has more to do with bad data than it has to do with SVR not capturing the model.